# How to stop iPhone from automatically dimming the brightness?

Tags: iphone, ios, display, auto-brightness

- I have unchecked Auto-Brightness under Settings app → General → Accessibility → Display Accommodations.
- I have also disabled Night Shift under Settings app → Display & Brightness.
- I have Low Power Mode turned off under Settings app → Battery.

However, every time I use the iPhone for either more than 5 minutes or use any apps, the brightness automatically dims down. It’s frustrating since I play games and use apps all the time. The brightness keeps fluctuating.

As I understand, there are no hardware faults. I believe this is purely a software bug. I would really like some help.

I am using an iPhone 7 running iOS 12.3.1.

Comment: What is the model of iPhone that you are using?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I am using an iPhone 7

Comment: Do you observe the brightness change while working in a single app or does the change occur only when switching between apps?

Comment: @NimeshNeema It dims once and then stays dimmed even if I switch through apps. I did observe that when I switch to a white background (some white wallpaper) it turns up again, but that happened once or twice. It usually stays dimmed for a while, and turns up by itself.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I had an iPhone 6 last month and it happened there as well. It also happened on another iPhone 8 I had. That is why I believe it is a software issue with ios 12 or later.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a hardware malfunction to me. I am writing this on an iPhone 7 and can confirm it’s not a software glitch in iOS. Advise to get it inspected by an authorized technician.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Like I said, I had 3 iPhones, and it happened on all of them. Apps and games dimmed the brightness. While using Instagram or watching a video, the brightness would dim down by itself. It happened on iPhone 6, iPhone 8 and now it is happening on my iPhone 7. My other friends have it too. They are also using iPhone 6 and 7. I have observed it on several different devices.

Comment: My 6S constantly adjusts its brightness, whatever I tell it to do. Not just down, both ways. [This is separate from what I have always assumed is heat protection, where it dims in hot sunlight]

Comment: @Tetsujin Any way you fixed it? And what do you mean by heat protection?

Comment: Never managed to make it behave any differently. It's most noticeable if I'm reading a book, black text on white background. I can just see the backlight slowly drifting up & down. The heat protection kicks in if the phone is in the sun, as it gets hot, it suddenly dims to about 50% & will not come back to full brightness until it cools.

Comment: @NimeshNeema The comment from Tetsujin made me realise that the same thing is happening to me. Flashlight is also turned off and it says I have to wait until iPhone cools down. Any way I can circumvent it?