# iPhone sometimes dims display quickly (a few seconds) even when Automatic Display and Brightness is turned off

Tags: iphone, display

My iPhone is over 90% charged - and in fact was connected to power. But it was dimming even just a few seconds after accepting a call. I could not look at another app on the phone since the display kept turning off (more than once). The phone call proceeded otherwise normally.

I have looked at this other question that talks about *five minutes* . That is short but nothing at all like about *five seconds*:   [How to stop iPhone from automatically dimming the brightness?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361961/how-to-stop-iphone-from-automatically-dimming-the-brightness)

This does not happen often but when it does it seems to only get resolved by entering into the Settings app and looking around (not necessarily even doing any changes).

What might be happening here - and is there a workaround/fix?   I have an iPhone6S and am on iOS 14.2

Comment: You mentioned it dims during the call? I know that it senses when you have your phone to the ear and switches the display off, to prevent you from accidentally pressing buttons on the touch screen. Once you take the phone off your ear, the sensors tell the display to switch back on. But this can sometimes stuff up and think you have the phone up to your ear when you don’t. I’m not sure if this is affecting you for other apps, but thought I’d explain that in case you didn’t know that. As to how you can fix that, I’m not sure sorry

Comment: thx for that info. the phone was not close to my ear - but as you say maybe the sensor thought it were. you could put an answer and i'd at the least upvote as helpful

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on my wife's 6S.  I've seen the "gunked up sensor" problem before, and in my experience, that will prevent the screen from coming on *at all* when moved away from the face.  This feels more like iOS has applied some type of "battery saver" plan (which she hasn't turned on by default).  Her phone is showing "Battery Health: `Service`" in Settings (with 79% capacity).  Any chance your battery is showing `Service`?